# Remove Google Ads from cached page for certain users

Tags: javascript, caching, mod-rewrite, ads, adsense

We run an ad supported wordpress blog and use WP Super Cache to cache the pages to pure HTML. The way it works, via mod_rewrite, totally bypasses php if a html copy of the file is available.

The problem stems from the fact that we use a "premium user" system in which the blog does not display ads for premium users.

Unfortunately this is not true for cached pages which, due to being pure HTML, cannot differentiate between premium and normal users.

The obvious way to go would be to use javascript to look the user up and hide the ad DOM elements. But modifications to Google Ads code are not allowed by the ToS.

Is there any way to stop google ads from displaying for some users? Maybe with some sort of asynchronous code that would make the ads load AFTER the user gets verified?

Would that violate the Terms of Service as well if the ad never gets triggered in the first place?

Comment: How is "not displaying" different from "removing" in the ToS?

Comment: @Diodeus - Very different. There is no obligation to display an ad. I can choose not to display an ad. It is forbidden to remove, hide or in any way modify an ad after it was placed as it encourages webmasters to publish ads that disappear after they get triggered creating false revenue or post them UNDER content where they still get counted but cannot be viewed. More info here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?utm_source=aso&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=ww-ww-et-asfe_#pla The link contains both ad placement limits and policies.

Comment: If the cached page refers to a stylesheet that is proxied through PHP you could hide the content without altering the DOM by offering two stylesheets. That's probably the least intrusive you can get with static pages.

Comment: That would be considered hiding ads, which is not allowed. My best bet would be using the new asynch code and only triggering it if necessary when ajax returns the user status value. The problem is: I don't know if it is against the ToS or not. Technically, it should be ok, because the code does not run until it gets authorized, so there are no "fake" impressions. But the last time I checked, loading ads via ajax, for instance, was not permitted.